# How to achieve server-side bidirectional flow timeout on message receive in gRPC Python?

Tags: grpc-python

Client send message to the Hello method which is bidirectional flow in grpc service.
Server receive the message from client and reply the HelloReply().

Here is what I would like to do:
If server does not receive any message from client within 2 seconds, abort the connection.
I attempt to do that with following codes, but not works...

Help is needed, thanks.

```py
class ServerServicer(service_pb2_grpc.HelloServicer):
    def Hello(self, request_iterator, context: grpc.ServicerContext):
        try:
        #     message_receive_time = time.time()
        #     def timeout():
        #         while True:
        #             if time.time() - message_receive_time > 2:
        #                 context.abort(grpc.StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, 'RPC Time Out!')
        #     timeout_task = threading.Thread(target=timeout)
        #     timeout_task.start()
            for request in request_iterator:
                message_receive_time = time.time()
                yield service_pb2.HelloReply()
        except Exception as error:
            traceback.print_exc()
        # timeout_task.close()
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "but not works"? The code commented out in your snippet looks like it should properly abort the RPC.